# Parsing within a field using SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, parsing, hive

We are receiving data in one column where further parsing is needed. In this example the separator is ~.
Goal is to grab the pass or fail value from its respective pair.

| SL | Data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "PARAM-0040,PASS~PARAM-0045,PASS~PARAM-0070,PASS" |
| 2 | "PARAM-0040,FAIL~PARAM-0045,FAIL~PARAM-0070,PASS" |

Required outcome:

| SL | PARAM-0040 | PARAM-0045 | PARAM-0070 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PASS | PASS | PASS |
| 2 | FAIL | FAIL | PASS |

This will be a part of a bigger SQL query where we are selecting many other columns, and these three columns are to be picked up from the source as well and passed in the query as selected columns.

E.g.

```
Select Column1, Column2, [ Parse code ] as PARAM-0040, [ Parse code ] as PARAM-0045, [ Parse code ] as PARAM-0070, Column6 .....
```

Thanks

Comment: you need to tag dbms you are using

Comment: done. This query is meant to extract data out of hive tables.

Comment: spark version ?

Comment: @Arctic Does the proposed answer using str_to_map work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with a regular expression. But regexps are non-standard.
This is how it is done in postgresql: REGEXP_MATCHES()

https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-regexp_matches/

In postgresql regexp_matches returns zero or more values. So then it has to be broken down (thus the {})

A simpler way, also in postgresql is to use substring.

substring('foobar' from 'o(.)b')

Like:

```
select substring('PARAM-0040,PASS~PARAM-0045,PASS~PARAM-0070,PASS' from 'PARAM-0040,([^~]+)~');
 substring 
-----------
 PASS
(1 row)
```

Comment: This looks like a good way to go. With regards to the answer being returned with "{...}". This then further needs cleaning.. is that a parameter to clean it on the result?

Comment: see updated answer. substring is simpler to use if you are using postgresql.

Comment: Substring was one thing that I thought of at first too, and it works perfectly.  Though, we do not know if the sequence of the data will be the same every time.

Comment: you can always craft a regular expression that is resilient to where the location is (basically, make the  regular expression end at the end of the string or in a tilde.

Comment: A combination of the two worked like a charm:
substring(regexp_extract(data, '(PARAM-0040,(.{4}))'), 12,4)

REGEXP_MATCHES() appears to not be in the list of functions available to us.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `str_to_map` function to split your data and subsequently extract each param's value. This example will first split each param/value pair by `~` before splitting the parameter and value by `,`.

Reproducible example with your sample data:

```sql
WITH my_table AS (
    SELECT 1 as SL, "PARAM-0040,PASS~PARAM-0045,PASS~PARAM-0070,PASS" as DATA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 as SL, "PARAM-0040,FAIL~PARAM-0045,FAIL~PARAM-0070,PASS" as DATA
),
param_mapped_data AS (
   SELECT SL, str_to_map(DATA,"~",",") param_map FROM my_table
)
SELECT
    SL,
    param_map['PARAM-0040'] AS  PARAM0040,
    param_map['PARAM-0045'] AS  PARAM0045,
    param_map['PARAM-0070'] AS  PARAM0070
FROM 
   param_mapped_data
```

Actual code assuming your table is named `my_table`

```sql
WITH param_mapped_data AS (
   SELECT SL, str_to_map(DATA,"~",",") param_map FROM my_table
)
SELECT
    SL,
    param_map['PARAM-0040'] AS  PARAM0040,
    param_map['PARAM-0045'] AS  PARAM0045,
    param_map['PARAM-0070'] AS  PARAM0070
FROM 
   param_mapped_data
```

Outputs:

| sl | param0040 | param0045 | param0070 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PASS | PASS | PASS |
| 2 | FAIL | FAIL | PASS |